# Best way to create Ruby on Rails metafields / custom fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture

I would like to create a custom fields system with Ruby on Rails, similar to what Shopify offers with metafields, or Hubspot with custom properties. https://knowledge.hubspot.com/crm-setup/manage-your-properties

I'm aware of the two usual ways of doing it: either a polymorphic relationship or store the custom fields in a jsonb column.

The custom fields will be display in a form, so for each row of one entity with a custom field, 
that will generate a "custom answer".

What I want to discuss, is, which solution would be better regarding performance?

Comment: very hard to say which one will be more performant, without seeing your use case, and without measuring, and without understanding what you are trying to do. the `shrine` gem stores the extra fields in an additional column as json data. I would suggest you try this approach and if that fails you can always revert to a different strategy later on down the line, if you cannot decide what to do.

Comment: What you are describing is a Entity Attribute Value (EAV)  table and it really does not have that much to do with polymorphic associations. While you can use a polymorphic association for the entity both are hacky enough on their own.